# How to change headlines of a theme with a click?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have two different themes,original and demo. With a click it should switch from original to demo,but with different headlines.
In the Manifest file is the string for the headline declared, but how can I change it from there?

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAppTheme" >
```

I just want to change the android:label.

Comment: Put some code here, preferably the whole `AndroidManifest` as minimum.

Answer (score 1):

**may be you can  try setTheme(YOUR_THEME); before calling setContentView(YOUR_XML); in activities..'

and you can define theme in your style xml

Comment: I know, but I want to change the app_name,if the button is clicked.

Comment: well at least you can not change your app_name because it will create the confusion on play store.. so it is immutable..